# SQL performance linq indexes

Tags: sql, performance, linq, indexing

I have a SQL database where i store routes. I store routeinformation in one table and the coordinates in another table.

Right now i have around 40 routes with 50k coordinates if you sum all routes.

I use the following LINQ code to get the data

```
var query = (from b in db.routes select new { 
                    name = b.name, 
                    id = b.route_id,
                    coor = b.coordinates.Select(c => new 
                    { 
                           seq = c.sequence,
                           lat = c.position.Latitude, 
                           lon = c.position.Longitude 
                    }) });
```

This query takes 4.5sec to execute, i find that to be kind.

I'm new to indexes, right now both primary-keys are clustered indexes, and primary keys are normal(??)-indexes that i created with the following SQL-command:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_route on [db].[coordinates] (route_id)
```

Is my database slow or is this normal for this amount of data?

Comment: If you run the query twice in rapid succession, is it still slow the 2nd time?

Comment: could you please show resulted generated SQL? I guess, it's not optimized, but it can help to rewrite linq query

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to see the SQL that is generated, run this in SSMS with the option to show the actual execution plan enabled. SSMS will suggest indexes that should improve the performance. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/12/29/SQL-Server-Management-Studio-2008-suggests-missing-indexes-with-actual.aspx

Comment: Perhaps `route_id` on the `coordinates` table should be the clustered index rather than on its primary key if this query is the type that will be its usual use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you can deal with your results flattened, this query might give you better performance:

```
            var query = from b in db.routes
                        from c in b.coordinates
                        select new
                        {
                            name = b.name,
                            id = b.route_id,
                            coor = new
                            {
                                seq = c.sequence,
                                lat = c.position.Latitude,
                                lon = c.position.Longitude
                            }
                        };
```